# Table does not render

Tags: tables

**Colors:**

```
\definecolor{lightcyan}{cmyk}{.20, 0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{medcyan}{cmyk}{.40, 0, 0, 0}
```

---

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{lrbox}{\referencetable}
        \begin{scriptsize}
            \begin{tabular}{|p{.975\linewidth}|}\hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|>{\columncolor{medcyan}}l|}{\color{black}\textbf{Test}}\cr\hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|>{\columncolor{lightcyan}}l|}{\color{black}\textbf{Text}}\cr\hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{scriptsize}
    \end{lrbox}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please edit your question so that it shows a complete example (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. Without this it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\begin{lrbox}{\referencetable}` saves its content as a local assignment to the box `\referencetable`.

As you do not use `\usebox{\referencetable}` the text is saved but never used so the `table` environment is completely empty.

As the assignment is a local assignment it is discarded at the end of the group `\end{table}` so you can not access the tabular at all.

The simplest initial fix would be to delete the lines `\begin{lrbox}{\referencetable}` and `\end{lrbox}`  then the table will appear, but presumably there was some intention to having the box.